# Substitution and make a list $ List[f[A, x]@{a1, a2}] =? \{f[a1,x],f[a2,x]\}$

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

For given list $\{a_1, \cdots, a_n\}$ and a function $f[a_,x]$, I want to make a function whose input is $[\{a1,\cdots, a_n\}, f[A,x]]$ and produce $\{ f[a_1,x], f[a_2, x], \cdots, f[a_n,x]\}$, i.e., plugging $a_1, a_2,$ into $a$ and make a list out of $f$.

My first trial was

```
 List[f[#, x]@{a1, a2}]
```

which seems bad. I know

```
  f@a1
```

produce $f[a1]$, and my simple idea was using this but it seems not working well

---

Simply I can make

```
 List[f[x, y] //. {x -> a1}, f[x, y] //. {x -> a2}]
```

and obtain the desired result but I want to make a simple code, not the code above.

Comment: `f[#, x] & /@ {a1, a2}`

Comment: Alternatively, you can just make a `Table`: `Table[f[k, x], {k, {a1, a2}}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many ways.

```
Table[f[i, x], {i, {a1, a2, a3}}]
```

But it's probably more typical to use table with an iterator expression rather than an explicit list. With an explicit list, Map is probably more typical:

```
f[#, x] & /@ {a1, a2, a3}
```

If you need to build something out of pieces fetched and brought together, might want

```
OperatorApplied[f][x] /@ {a1, a2, a3}
```

I often do my own currying with SubValues:

```
f[param_][arg_] := f[param, arg];
f[x] /@ {a1, a2, a3}
```

This actually switched the order, but I like my *parameters* to come before regular arguments. Or course, you could have done

```
f[param_][arg_] := f[arg, param]
```

Or

```
Thread[f[{a1, a2, a3}, x]]
```

`Construct` sometimes comes in handy. The list goes on...